# Problem with sessions on weblogic

Tags: java, session, weblogic

i've faced a strange problem with weblogic. One of our workstations hosts 2 weblogic instances. The problem is when i log in to one of them, session on another automatically expires and vice versa. What can it be? How to deal with this problem?

Comment: Same login id on both machines?  Are you logging in as an admin?

Comment: What do you mean by login id? It doesn't matter under which user i log in, anyway session on another instance automatically expires.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the session id is stored within a cookie on the client side, make sure the cookie name is not the same on both your weblogic instances.

One way to change the cookie name is to create a file named *weblogic.xml* in your webapps (or *weblogic-application.xml* in your EARs, just replace the tag *weblogic-web-app* by *weblogic-application*) containing the following (customize the cookie name according to your needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
    <session-descriptor>
        <cookie-name>MyCookieName</cookie-name>
    </session-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: well, i'll try to, but actually it's one the same application (not physically, of course) runs on both instances: one is for development needs, another is for tests. So, actually both applications have the same weblogic.xml. But more strange that same problem sometimes occur on another workstation with our demo weblogic instance and jira. For some reason some users experience same problem with them: when user logs in to jira he automatically logs out from weblogic and vice versa. This is very strange considering that it occurs only with some selected users.

Comment: mukola I assume that you are running out of different wars/deployments. So have variations on the weblogic.xml for the different deployments

Comment: On WebLogic 8 this is still set in session-descriptor but you have to add it as a <session-param> name/value pair, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html. Ex: <session-param> <param-name>CookieName</param-name> <param-value>TESTSESSION</param-value>

Answer (score 1):

since they are running on the same machine, your browser sees one host (i.e. localhost). since the default session cookie for java webapps is JSESSIONID and both are using this cookiename they will overwrite each other.

A solution is to open 2 IE browser windows by starting IE twice. In that case they will get their own session cookie. Unfortunalty this doesn't work for Firefox and Chrome.

An other solution is mentioned by nawre, by giving the 2 webapps a different session cookie name.